# Help me prove congruency

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

[image]

i)

$AX = BC$ (given)

$AD = CY$ (given since $AX = CY = BC$ and $BC = AD$ in a parallelogram)

$\widehat{DAX} =  \widehat{YCB}$ (equal opp. angles in a parallelogram)

Therefore $ADX$ and $CBY$ are congruent

Now this is my solution to this question, is it mathematically valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line "$\angle DAX=\angle YCB$ since equal opp angles in parallelogram" needs some work.

Either you are referring to some rule I have not heard of, or else you are misapplying the one I have heard of, which would say that $\angle ACX=\angle YBC$. I don't think it's the first one because a property of parallelograms would not refer to these extra points $X,Y$ which are not a common feature of parallelograms.

To get you going again on a solution, work to show $AX\parallel YC$. here are two hints:

(I'm also going to assume that the diagram is meant to further convey the hypothesis that $X$ does not lie directly on $D$.)

Hint 1: Look at the two isosceles triangles.

Hint 2: Look at $\angle BYC$ and $\angle AXD$.

Comment: What I mean to say is that opposite sides in a parallelogram are equal,

Comment: @Alatma That is true but it does not sound anything like what you wrote. What side does $<DAX$ refer to?

Comment: I think it meant to be angle DAB and I made a mistake, DAB = DCB

Comment: @Alatma $\angle DAB$ also does not seem very relevant, although I could be wrong. How about you think about it carefully for a few more minutes, then comment again here about what you really meant to say.

Comment: can you show me your solution? this is not homework but for test revision

Comment: @Alatma I added hints.